# VBA Area of a Triangle

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and I can't get this code to work. Any ideas? It's for an assignment so has to be formatted like this I keep getting an error on 'Display Area.

```
Private Sub cmbOK_Click()
'Declare variables
Dim TriBase As Single
Dim TriHeight As Single
Dim TriArea As Single
'Set the variables to the values in the textboxes
TriBase = Val(txtBase.Text)
TriHeight = Val(txtHeight.Text)
'Calculate area
TriArea = (TriBase * TriHeight) * 0.5
'Display area
lblArea.Text = Str(TriArea)
```

Comment: Please try lblArea.Caption = Str(TriArea)

Comment: What is the error?  A type conversion based error? What is the value of TriArea at error?

Comment: Please don't post a question without describing the error. Please post the actual error

Comment: Voted up because you showed the effort towards a solution as well as saying it was for an assignment. Good example.

Answer (score 1):

The visible part of a `Label` is its `Caption`.
You may also want to shorten the shown decimals by `Format`.
If the precision of your calculation has to be higher, change from `Single` to `Double`.

```
Private Sub cmbOK_Click()
    'Declare variables
    Dim TriBase As Single
    Dim TriHeight As Single
    Dim TriArea As Single
    'Set the variables to the values in the textboxes
    TriBase = Val(txtBase.Text)
    TriHeight = Val(txtHeight.Text)
    'Calculate area
    TriArea = TriBase * TriHeight * 0.5
    'Display area
    lblArea.Caption = Format(TriArea, "0.00")
End Sub
```